# Proof verification: $\gcd(m,n) = 1 \implies \mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n \cong \mathbb{Z}/{mn}$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that if $m,n$ are relatively prime, $\mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n \cong \mathbb{Z}/mn$ as groups under addition. Here is my attempt. I'm going to use multiplicative notation, but I acknowledge that the groups are abelian and therefore it's more natural to use additive notation. I'm going to use the below two lemmas without proof.

> **Lemma 1**: Any two finite cyclic groups of order $k$ are isomorphic.
>
> **Lemma 2**: If $a \in G$ is an element of order $n$ and $a^k = e$, then $n \mid k$.

> Consider the element $(1,1) \in \mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n$. If $(1,1)^k = (0,0)$, then $1^k = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/m$ and $1^k = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/n$; in $\mathbb{Z}/m$, $|1| = m$ and in $\mathbb{Z}/n$, $|1| = n$. By Lemma 2, $m \mid k$ and $n \mid k$. As $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, we have $mn \mid k$.

I'm trying to show that $|(1,1)| = mn$, which would require that $k \mid mn$. I'm not sure how to deduce this from the fact that $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. If I prove this, then $(1,1)$ has the same order as $\mathbb{Z}/m \times \mathbb{Z}/n$, so it generates the group. But $\mathbb{Z}/mn$ is also cyclic of order $mn$ generated by $1$, so by the lemma, these two cyclic groups are isomorphic.

My questions are:

1. How do I prove that $mn = k$?
2. Is there a different, more natural proof strategy for this fact, or is this the standard proof?

Comment: We clearly have $(1,1)^{mn}=(0,0)$. As you have shown, if $(1,1)^k=(0,0)$ then $mn|k$. So it follows immediately that $mn$ is the order of $(1,1)$, this is the smallest $k\geq 1$ such that $(1,1)^k=(0,0)$.

Comment: Compare also with the standard proofs, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795919/mathbb-z-mn-isomorphic-to-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n-whenever-m-and) for rings, which gives it for the additive groups as well.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318606/if-gcdm-n-1-then-mathbbz-n-times-mathbbz-m-is-cyclic), or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445907/the-product-of-finitely-many-cyclic-groups-is-cyclic) etc.

Comment: Your notation is confusing... Using exponents indicates multiplicative group notation, whereas the neutral element $(0,0)$ indicates additive notation.